# How can I make a QMap object emit a signal when `QMap::insert(...)` is called?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qobject, qmap

Pretty straightforward question.

`QMap` does not inherit `QObject`, so I'd like to know if there is an easy Qt Way of making it `emit mySignal(MyEnum state)`.

If you are asking why I do not just emit a signal in my code when I call the function `QMap::insert(...)`, its because this is done in a template... which """I think""" is impossible:

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/templates.html

If it helps, the `QMap` object I am using is global, and will be used between threads.

Comment: Just create in your app global extern(?) QObject for emit some signals and use this object when you need connect (queued connections for threads) or/and emit signals ( emit mySignalsObject.foo() ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy:

```
class MyMap : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT;
public slots:
    void insert(... key, ... value)
    {
        _map.insert(key, value);
        emit isInserted(key);
    }
signals:
    void isInserted(... key);
private:
    QMap<..., ...> _map;
}
```